# how to create multiple contours on a scatter plot in python

Tags: python, scatter-plot, contour

I have a dataframe in which I have 3 columns each representing latitude, longitude and elevation of the point.
[image]

I would like to create a bathymetric map of the seabed. With the code below I obtain the following map:

```
Df2D = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Df.csv', header = 0, delimiter=';')

Y = Df2D['lat'].values
X = Df2D['lon'].values
Z = Df2D['elevation'].values

plt.scatter(X,Y, c=Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, however, I would like to add contours to precise values (e.g., 0m, -10m,-50m,...) to have a more detailed map of the seabed. I tried with plt.tricontour but the result is not so good, also because it shows only one contour :

```
plt.tricontour(X, Y, Z, 0, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
plt.tricontourf(X, Y, Z, 0)
```

[image]

Any ideas to increase the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure if `tricontour` is what you're after or just `contour`. You didn't talk about triangulation in your post.

But either way, after specifying `X, Y, Z`, in both these functions the next arg is called `levels`. If you pass an integer  `n` here (in your case, `0`), the contour plot will have *at most* `n+1` levels. If instead you pass an array, it will use the values of the array as levels.

Long story short, replace `0` with `[0, -10, -50, -100]` to get contour lines at exactly those levels.